# mysql full text search "next" ; no result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE `title` LIKE '%next%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE `title` LIKE 'next'
```

i can get results from the searches which are written above.

but; i cannot get any result with the code which is written below.

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST('next') AS relevant
FROM video  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('next' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevant DESC
```

how can i get a result from the search of "next" word via "fulltext-search" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the next problem and I found the answer here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

There is in fact a list of stop words that will not be returned when you try to do your fulltext search